# Collect from several stateflows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I have 2 stateFlow's in my viewModel. To collect them in fragment I have to launch coroutines 2 times as below:

```
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        stocksVM.quotes.collect {
            if (it is Resource.Success) {
                it.data?.let { list ->
                    quoteAdapter.submitData(list)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        stocksVM.stockUpdate.collect {
            log(it.data?.data.toString())
        }
    }
```

If I have more stateFlow's, I have to launch coroutines respectively. Is there a better way to handle multiple stateFlow's in my Fragment/Activity or wherever?

Comment: What is stopping you from collecting in one scope itself? Like if you launch `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {}` can't you just `stocksVM.quotes.collect{}` and `stocksVM.stockUpdate.collect {}` inside it only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Because collect() is a suspending function inside a coroutine and it will suspend until my flow stops, thus my next collect() will not be called until the previous flow terminates @che10

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You will need different coroutines, since `collect()` is a suspending function that suspends until your `Flow` terminates.

For collecting multiple flows the currently recommended way is:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch {
          stocksVM.quotes.collect { ... }   
        }
    
        launch {
            stocksVM.stockUpdate.collect { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the problem with `launchWhenStarted` is that while your newly emitted items will not be processed your producer will still run in the background.

I'd definitely give this a read, as it explains the current best-practices really well: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Comment: I tried it exactky this way and it doesn't work. Only the first launch{} works. Subsequent launch blocks lie there with no action.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is wondering how to emit multiple flows in the same block of `viewModelScope.launch`, it is the same as Robert's answer. i.e as follows

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    launch {
        exampleFlow1.emit(data)
    }
    launch {
        exampleFlow2.emit(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can choose to mix multiple streams.

### Use the function `merge` or `combine` in `kotlin`. Of course, the usage of these two functions is different.

---

Add:

If Flow is not processed, open multiple Coroutines to collect():

```kotlin
fun main() {
    collectFlow()
}

fun emitStringElem(): Flow<String> = flow {
    repeat(5) {
        delay(10)
        emit("elem_$it")
    }
}

fun emitIntElem(): Flow<Int> = flow {
    repeat(10) {
        delay(10)
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

Open two coroutine collections
result is:

```
From int Flow: item is: 0
From string Flow: item is: elem_0
From int Flow: item is: 1
From string Flow: item is: elem_1
From int Flow: item is: 2
From string Flow: item is: elem_2
From int Flow: item is: 3
From string Flow: item is: elem_3
From int Flow: item is: 4
From string Flow: item is: elem_4
From int Flow: item is: 5
From int Flow: item is: 6
From int Flow: item is: 7
From int Flow: item is: 8
From int Flow: item is: 9
```

Merge two flows

```kotlin
fun margeFlow() = runBlocking {
    merge(
        emitIntElem().map {
            it.toString()
        }, emitStringElem()
    ).collect {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

result is :

```
0
elem_0
1
elem_1
2
elem_2
3
elem_3
4
elem_4
5
6
7
8
9
```

conbine two flows:

```kotlin
fun combineFlow() = runBlocking {
    combine(emitIntElem(), emitStringElem()) { int: Int, str: String ->
        "$int combine $str"
    }.collect {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

result is:

```
0 combine elem_0
1 combine elem_0
1 combine elem_1
2 combine elem_2
3 combine elem_3
4 combine elem_4
5 combine elem_4
6 combine elem_4
7 combine elem_4
8 combine elem_4
9 combine elem_4
```

Comment: Docs: [merge](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html), [combine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html)

Answer (score 7):

Like @RóbertNagy said, you shouldn't use `launchWhenStarted`. But there is an alternate syntax for doing it the proper way without having to do the nested `launch`es:

```
stocksVM.quotes
    .flowOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    .onEach { 
        if (it is Resource.Success) {
            it.data?.let { list ->
                quoteAdapter.submitData(list)
            }
        }
    }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)

stocksVM.stockUpdate
    .flowOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    .onEach { 
        log(it.data?.data.toString())
    }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: This requires `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'` dependency.
More here -> https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda